# Упоминание роли через бота с помощью discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Перепробовал все методы которые находил в интернете и документации discord.py, сначало вроде получилось, но бот не пингует роль так что бы она подсвечивалась желтым светом, мне это важно. пробовал что-то типа такого:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:  # чтобы бот не отвечал сам себе
            return

        if message.content.startswith(''):
            await channel.send(f"<@" + str(883304543780216832) + ">")
```

Мне это не помогло. роль вроде упоминает через айди, но это все же не то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты можешь её упомянуть вот так, для этого используй символ &:

```
await channel.send("<@&883304543780216832>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Взять объект роли через

```
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
role.mention
```